# How to change text color individual item dynamically?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

How to change text color individual item of listview dynamically?
I want to implement the following function in Android.

1. Call API regularly and get each price data
2. Print in listview
3. Calculate each price margin
4. If a certain item's margin is minus, change color to red. plus is green.

This function is often seen in Cryptocurrency Apps. 
like that 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuCkg_P6_Ws

I implemented 1, 2, and 3. 
How to implement 4?
If you know anything about that please let me know.

```
public class CoinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CoinItem> {
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ArrayList<CoinItem> coinItem;
float x;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CoinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CoinItem> {
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ArrayList<CoinItem> coinItem;
float x;


public CoinAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<CoinItem> coinItem) {
    super(context, resource, coinItem);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.coinItem = coinItem;
}

public float diff(String btc_last, String btc_prelast) {
    x = Float.parseFloat(btc_last) - Float.parseFloat(btc_prelast);
    return x;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ticker, null);
    }

    ImageView icon_coin = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_coin);
    icon_coin.setImageBitmap(coinItem.get(position).getIcon_coin());

    TextView text_last = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_last);
    text_last.setText(coinItem.get(position).getText_last() + "円");
    if (x > 0) text_last.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    else if (x < 0) text_last.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    else text_last.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    TextView text_coin = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_coin);
    text_coin.setText(coinItem.get(position).getText_coin());

    TextView text_bid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_bid);
    text_bid.setText("売値");

    TextView text_bid_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_bid_price);
    text_bid_price.setText(coinItem.get(position).getText_bid_price() + "円");

    TextView text_ask = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_ask);
    text_ask.setText("買値");

    TextView text_ask_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_ask_price);
    text_ask_price.setText(coinItem.get(position).getText_ask_price() + "円");

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Calling API code is like that

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 1000;
    btc_prelast="0";
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            coin_btc.clone().enqueue(new Callback<Ticker>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Ticker> call, Response<Ticker> response) {
                    btc_last = Float.toString(response.body().getLast());
                    btc_bid = Float.toString(response.body().getBid());
                    btc_ask = Float.toString(response.body().getAsk());
                    coinItem.set(0, new CoinItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), icon_coin[0]), btc_last, name_coin[0], btc_bid, btc_ask));
                    coinAdapter.diff(btc_last,btc_prelast);
                    btc_prelast = btc_last;
                    coinAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Ticker> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Post your adapter code

Comment: I tried but this way changes all item color at the same time

Comment: Post the your adapter code

Comment: Check the answer @NooNoo

Comment: I add the code , sorry

Comment: Why you check position just check your x value and change color of TextView.

Comment: sorry position was used to test change color

Comment: I answered the same thing

Comment: That put your else condition

Comment: Sorry I am not good english..."test" means "as a test"

Comment: thanks! The problem is now resolved!

Comment: @NooNoo - You should probably also be using RecyclerView not ListView

Comment: OK. I heard recyvlerview is difficult but efficient...I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple putting the else condition would work.

Assuming your default colour for TextView is Black.

```
if(x < 0 ){
  textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}else if(x > 0){
  textview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}else{
  //your textview default colour
  textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: I have 12 items and this way change all item. So I use position but listview is recycled , so out of screen item is also change

Comment: So Use this code. It will help you. I understand your issue

Comment: Check this answer @NooNoo

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that inside your listview you already have a `TextView` in the layout. All you have to do is call TextView#setTextColor. An example would be:

```
TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textviewname);
t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: I have 12 items and this way change all item. So I use position but listview is recycled , so out of screen item is also change

Answer (score 0):

In your Getview Method,
Check your margin.

```
    if(margin > 0){textview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);}
    else if(margin < 0){textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);}
    else {textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);}
```

Check this codition.

Comment: Please share code if query is exist, else glad to hear your query has resolved.